# bumblebee daemon requires manual restart to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, mint

At first:

```
$ optirun vlc
[16127.891535] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[16127.891591] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

and then i do magic trick:

```
# ps aux | grep bumblebee
root      1138  0.0  0.0  36232  1872 ?        Ss   17:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/bumblebeed --daemon
# kill 1138
# service bumblebeed start
```

because simple way doesn't work:

```
# service bumblebeed restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
bumblebeed start/running, process 6481
```

how to make it work right after boot? here some maybe useful data:

[dpkg --list | grep nvidia](http://pastebin.com/t2iZNfwY)

[/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf](http://pastebin.com/3vHWUqvB)

```
# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need to do the following:
1. Bumblebee demon should be running as root (which it was at first start). You then killed the daemon and ran it as yourself (in userspace). So don't kill the daemon if it is running when you first boot
2. Add your username into the bumblebee group (`adduser <user> bumblebee`). Create the group if it doesn't already exist
3. In your bumblebee.conf file, change all occurences of nvidia-current to nvidia-352

Comment: 1) i kill the daemon and run it as root, after 'su' command. because type sudo everywhere i need elevation in CLI is annoying.
2) already in group
3) not helped
||
i think i'll just make .sh script and forget about it :D horrible solution buy it will work

Comment: also, #3 screwed my optirun completely, restart didnt worked and i restored old version